# Did commerical flag makers catalog and sell the second Confederate national flag as "whiteman's flag"?

Tags: united-states, history

According to the 1957 [Stevens-Davis and allied families: a memorial volume of history , biography, and genealogy](https://books.google.com/books?id=VkZVAAAAMAAJ&q=Flag%20makers%20have%20contracted%20the%20phrase&dq=Flag%20makers%20have%20contracted%20the%20phrase&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2ws-mle7WAhVCLSYKHR67AwIQ6AEIJjAA) :

> Commercially, this design is called the "Whiteman flag" or "White-man design", the term a contraction of a phrase used in another Thompson editorial, a paragraph of which reads: "Such a flag would be a suitable emblem of our young Confederacy, and, sustained by the brave hearts and strong arms of the South, it would take rank among the proudest ensigns of the nations, and be hailed by the civilized world as "THE WHITE MAN'S FLAG." (a) . Flag makers have contracted the phrase, "THE WHITE MAN'S FLAG", into "Whiteman's flag" or "Whiteman's design", and under that name this flag is catalogued and sold.

Is there independent evidence for or against this being true, that the [second Confederate national flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_the_Confederate_States_of_America) was cataloged and sold as "Whiteman's flag"?

(This question is inspired by, but not a duplicate of, [another question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/did-william-t-thompson-design-a-flag-with-explicit-white-supremacist-symbolism?noredirect=1&lq=1) about the flag.  The present question is specifically about what name flag makers catalogued and sold the flag under, and is not asking about who designed the flag or the reasoning behind the design of the flag.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did William T. Thompson design a flag with explicit white supremacist symbolism, which was adopted by the US Confederacy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/did-william-t-thompson-design-a-flag-with-explicit-white-supremacist-symbolism)

Comment: @ventsyv This is a different question, particularly, regardless of who designed the flag, was it catalogued and sold as "Whiteman's flag"?

Comment: In the accepted answer, an article from the 1860s is cited that calls it "whiteman's flag". This seems to support the notion that the confederate flag was commonly referred to as "whiteman's flag". Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ventsyv That's my answer, no it doesn't answer my question here.  The 1957 book that this question is about, quotes the 1860s Thompson article, and then says that flag makers started cataloguing and selling the flag under the name "whiteman's flag".  This question is specifically about what commercial flag makers called the flag when they sold it.  Was it "stainless banner", "Jackson flag" or "whiteman's flag" or something else?

Comment: Surely this question could be trivially answered by looking at a few flag catalogues?

Comment: @jamesqf that would be an ideal answer if you could find it in pre-1957 catalogs